# Plotly figures not showing up on github-hosted site?

Tags: python, plotly, github-pages

I'm having some trouble with Plotly (Python) figures not being rendered on my github-hosted website (here: https://degravek.github.io/project-pages/). In order to make the posts on that site, I have to upload a .ipynb file. When I do this, though, the Plotly figures do not show up for some reason. Some googling doesn't seem to shed much light on the problem. Other figures plotted using seaborn or pandas show up just fine though. Anyone else have this problem and know how to solve it?